# Built-in classes metaclass in Python

Tags: python, metaclass

Are there any built-in Python classes that are not instances of `type` metaclass?

```
>>> type(list)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(some_builtin_python_class)
<type 'some_type_other_than_type'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "built-in". If you mean any of the C-implemented (in CPython) classes exposed as builtins (and in `builtin`), then no, none of them have a different metaclass.<sup>*</sup>

But there are definitely classes in the stdlib that do. For example:

```
>>> type(collections.abc.Iterable)
abc.ABCMeta
```

To clarify: Other metaclasses are of course subclasses of type, so, by the normal inheritance rules, it's still true that `isinstance(Iterable, type)`—but it's not true that `type(Iterable) == type`. Which is what you were asking for in your question—a type for which `type(T)` returns `<type 'some_type_other_than_type'>`.

---

<sub>* Not in 3.x, at any rate. Things were different in 2.x, where there were classic classes, and, once upon a time, "fake classes" that were actually functions that looked like `type` instances but weren't, and returned instances of a hidden `type` instance when called.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I mean `builtin` module in python. Anyway, you are right, there are no such classes in this module. I've [just checked it](https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/6c2f66f2e1b2e191a91313264e19093c)

Comment: @IvanKalita: Much cleaner than my own check. I didn't use `inspect` because I wanted to run it against 2.4, but then I couldn't find my working 2.4 installation, so it was all a waste… :)

Comment: Although even collections.abc.Iterable is an instance of type. `isinstance(collections.abc.Iterable, type)` is `True`.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Sure—metaclasses are subclasses of `type`, so classes with custom metaclasses are instances of `type`. But that's just normal inheritance; I assume he meant `type(x) == type`, not `instance(x, type)`.

Comment: This answer is plain incorrect, as other metaclasses in the stdlib are also descendant of type: `type(Iterable).__mro__` yields `(abc.ABCMeta, type, object)`

Comment: And of course, `isinstance(Iterable, type)` returns True - hence "plain incorrect" as it is.

Comment: @jsbueno: Also, read the question: He is looking for some type T for which `type(T)` returns `<type 'some_type_other_than_type'>`. Which is definitely true for `Iterable`. So I've answered exactly what he asked, and what he asked was perfectly sensible. I've updated the answer to make it clearer, but I don't think it was in any way wrong before.